# Category RSS Feed - Article Title not being detected

Tags: rss

When i run my category RSS feed W3C seems to think there is no "title" attribute per article.  Ive checked the source of the RSS in FF and Chrome and i see a title being outputted.

We tested in mailchimp as well, and they cant detect the title either,  can anyone see what is wrong.  Here is the feed.
http://lh-gtsblog.com/category/lh-intouch-news/feed/

We have a demo site as well - http://lh-gtsblog.feedmybeta.com/category/lh-intouch-news/feed/

Is this a problem with the validators or my actual feed? What can i do to fix?  any suggestions?

PS it seems to be an Atom feed.

Comment: Looks like you have empty `<title></title>` in the feed itself for all items. Maybe you're viewing a cached feed in your browser, where the title is set for all items. Could be a theme or plugin related issue.

Comment: Try deactivating `lsx-login` plugin & then check in validator & mailchimp. If the RSS feed works fine after plugin deactivation, then activated it again and add `remove_filter( 'the_title', 'the_title_filter' );` in your theme's functions.php file and check the feed again in validator and mailchimp. I think this shall work.